# Flyway doesn't work with SQL Server 2000?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000, flyway

Someone know how to use Flyway with SQL Server 2000?

Comment: Have you tried it? Did you get some error? What is it?

Comment: Yes, I did. When I use SQL Server 2008 works fine, but using SQL Server 2000 i get error.

Comment: Sql Server 2000 is way past end of life. It no longer gets any patches, even for critical security issues, and hasn't for some time now. Continuing to use it is highly irresponsible. Upgrading this server is job 1.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, I did. When I use SQL Server 2008 works fine, but using SQL Server 2000 i get this error:

> jul 14, 2016 6:31:09 PM
>   org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.logging.apachecommons.ApacheCommonsLog
>   info INFORMAÇÕES: Database:
>   jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://10.211.55.7:1433/hemovida (Microsoft SQL Server
>   8.0) Error: Unable to retrieve the current schema for the connection

My code is:

```
    Flyway flyway = new Flyway();
    flyway.setDataSource("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://10.211.55.7:1433/dataTest", "sa", "123");
    flyway.setInitOnMigrate(true);
    flyway.setValidateOnMigrate(false);
    try {
        flyway.migrate();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
```

My migration file is:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table(
   name varchar(10) NOT NULL
);
```

I dont know why!